# I'm established user, why I can't see the downvotes and upvotes in the questions?

Tags: support, privileges

When we reach 1000 points in MSE, we can have so many privileges, such as view the vote counts on posts, I can't see any way, someone knows what happens?

Thanks

Comment: Rafael: Congratulations!

Comment: @amWhy thanks :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Click on the vote count of any post; you will see the breakdown.[image]

You can find more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user).

Answer (score 6):

To view the up and down vote breakdown, click on the vote total, and that should then display the up and down votes.

Comment: where can I see this bottom "vote total"?

Comment: I got it!!!! :D