# Lost points explanation

Tags: support, reputation

(It's been suggested that this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6904). It's not: I didn't want to see the upvote/downvote tally (although this would have resolved my confusion!), I wanted an explanation for deducted points. Another user with the same confusion would not be likely to find the linked question.)

I answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045110/how-to-find-the-set-of-all-points-in-a-submanifold-minimizing-the-distance-to-a/3045245#3045245) a day or so ago, engaged in lots of interaction with the OP, and finally expanded my answer to include a little extra yesterday. Today I find my "Achievements" have a "-2" associated with this question. There are no downvotes in sight. Can someone explain the point-loss?

I want to be clear: I don't think I'd change anything about my answer, but if I'm missing something about the rules, I'd like to know it. It's a little like the 1970s, when you could drive across a state line in the US into a state that didn't have a "right turn on red" law, and suddenly be doing something stupid and dangerous without knowing it. If I'm that person, I'd like to know. :)

Comment: If you click on the net votes of your answer, which currently displays as $0$, you can obtain a count of upvotes and downvotes received on the answer, and doing that, you'll see someone did downvote the answer: +1, -1 (One upvote, one downvote yielding net zero votes.)

Comment: Thanks. Live and learn!

Comment: You can still drive across a line into New York City, which has no "right turn on red".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see on [your reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/114036/john-hughes?tab=reputation) that this was indeed caused by downvote.

You can check that there was a downvote also on the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3045245/timeline) of the post. And you can click on the score to see the numbers of downvotes and upvotes. (The latter only works for users with at least 1k reputation points.)

See also:

- [How to see questions time line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826)
- [How do I view vote counts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)
- [I'm established user, why I can't see the downvotes and upvotes in the questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6904)

Comment: Of course! I saw the "0" next to the question and thought "I have no downvotes!" but what I actually have is an equal number of up- and down-votes. D'oh! Thanks!